# As only display text with substr()

Tags: php, html, substr

On the basis of data I have saved an article that comes with HTML as `<br>, <table> ... etc. ....`

example :

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:50%;text-align:left;">Temas nuevos - Comunidad</td>
    <td class="blocksubhead" style="width:50%;text-align:left;">Temas actualizados - Comunidad Temas actualizados - Comunidad</td>
</tr>
```

What I want is displayed on another screen a summary of the article using substr (), my problem is I can not print what I want, and that prints the html code eta first.

Example: `echo substr($row["news"], 0, 20);`

It is printing the first 20 characters, it only show at browser:

```
<td style="width:50%;text-align:l<td/>
```

What I want is, it only show the text and discard the html code it has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strip_tags()` to strip html etc from the string...

So: `echo substr(strip_tags($row["news"]), 0, 20);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

You *could* also do it using `preg_replace()` to match and replace anything that looks like a tag :)

Answer (score 0):

The strip_tags() function strips a string from HTML, XML, and PHP tags.

```
//remove the html from the string.
$row["news"] = strip_tags($row["news"]);

//getting the first 20 character from the string and display as output.
echo substr($row["news"], 0, 20);
```